# Return tag name from a segment in Tagger

Tags: devdemon-tagger

I'm pulling tagged entries via segment_3. When I'm showing this page, I'd like to have it titled "SEARCH FOR: {TAG}". Problem is that nowhere in the documentation can I tell where you can pull the tag name out from a segment....

Tried getting complex with this but it pulled all tags:

```
   <h1>SEARCH FOR:
    {exp:tagger:entries tag="{segment_3}" limit="1"}
      {exp:tagger:tags entry_id="{tagger:entry_id}"}
        {tagger:tag_name}
      {/exp:tagger:tags}
    {/exp:tagger:entries}
  </h1>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you check this out in the [documentation](http://www.devdemon.com/documentation/tag/decode-tag/)?

```
{exp:tagger:tagname tag="{segment_3}"}
```

Comment: Checked every section but that one.... thanks!

Comment: Don't forget to mark this question as answered.